# Can't upload APNS dev certificate for GCM - Unknown Error

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to upload a development APNS certificate to GCM at the "Obtain a Configuration File" step.  I've tried different certs/p12 files as well as different app/bundle ids and nothing will let me upload the certificate.  What's odd is that production certificate uploads okay.  See screen shot.  Any idea why this would happen?[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got a support response from google and what worked for me was to make a new app id in and app name/bundle id that matched.  What I was doing before that didn't work:

- **iOS app ID:** com.project.MyAppIOS
- **google app name:** my app
- **bundle ID:** com.project.MyAppIOS

This worked:

- **iOS app ID:** com.project.MyApp
- **google app name:** MyApp
- **bundle ID:** com.project.MyApp

Thanks google for the quick response and help

Comment: You should go on ahead and accept this as the correct answer, so that your question is properly tagged as already answered. Cheers! :)